# Theme filter for a view

Tags: views, 8

How can I theme filters for a view in drupal 8? 
I would like to place the filters to the sidebar menu, and rather than having standard either dropdown or autocomplete field, I would like to have something like a rendered block, so that a user could see all options at a glance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need install module [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters)

Answer (score 1):

Install [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) and if you want to have a filter as a rendered block you can edit view and see `Exposed form in block:` option under `EXPOSED FORM`. Enable it as `Yes` and place block in any page as you like.

[image]